# Prevent table from overflowing parent container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox layout, in one of the columns I have a table (see green box) which should use scroll bars if the table is too wide / the window size is reduced.

The problem is, if you reduce the horizontal window size the horizontal scrollbars get cut off. In fact the scrollbar also only shows if you make the window smaller than what you would expect. I assume the reason is the first red column in the layout. The second column assumes the total width is 100% but in reality it is `100% - first` column. Just try to remove the first `<nav></nav>` tags and test it again and you should see that the scrollbar is now not cut off and works as expected.

**How do make it so the horizontal scroll bar is not cut off?**

Unfortunately: `display: table-layout`, fixed widths, or `calc(100% - ?px)` are not a solution.

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/8vw91tyj/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add `overflow-x: auto` and everything works fine

```
#container {
  ...
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

main nav {
  background: red;
  min-width: 200px;
}

#search {
  background: purple;
}

#container {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#container nav {
  background: orange;
}

.portlet {
  background: yellow;
}

.p-main {
  overflow-x: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

table {
  background: green;
  width: 600px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <nav>Nav</nav>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="search">Search</div>
    <div class="portlet">
      <div class="p-head">Head</div>
      <div class="p-main">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>ASDF</td>
            <td>ASDF</td>
            <td>ASDF</td>
            <td>ASDF</td>
            <tr>
              <td>ASDF</td>
              <td>ASDF</td>
              <td>ASDF</td>
              <td>ASDF</td>
              <tr>
                <td>ASDF</td>
                <td>ASDF</td>
                <td>ASDF</td>
                <td>ASDF</td>
                <tr>
                  <td>ASDF</td>
                  <td>ASDF</td>
                  <td>ASDF</td>
                  <td>ASDF</td>
                  <tr>
                    <td>ASDF</td>
                    <td>ASDF</td>
                    <td>ASDF</td>
                    <td>ASDF</td>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="p-foot">Foot</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```